# Initialize another react component from other component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have many `td`'s. On click on each of the `td`'s I want to render a altogether new component. How would I do that?

`Compon1` `render` method looks like this:

```
<tbody>
       {this.props.comments.map((comment, i) =>
            <tr>
               <td onClick={() => <Comp2 passOnData={comment}}><p>comment.text</p></td>
            </tr>
       )}
</tbody>
```

I expect the `Comp2` should be rendered when I click on each of the `td`'s, but that is not happening.

However its not throwing any error/warning also in the console.

Since I'm new to react, I might be doing this in wrong way;

Comment: I didnt quite catch what you want to happen. What will be rendered inside the <td> when it hasnt been clicked yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [states](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate) - [`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/_alexander_/69z2wepo/20241/), like this

```
var Comment = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    let comments = this.props.comment.child.map((comment, index) => {
      return <li key={index}>{comment}</li>;
    });

    return <ul>
      { comments }
    </ul>;
  }
});

var Comments = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      comments: this.props.comments
    }
  },

  handleToggle: function (comment) {
    let comments = this.state.comments.map((el) => {
      el.isActive = (el.id === comment.id) ? !el.isActive : el.isActive
      return el;
    });

    this.setState({ comments: comments });
  },

  render: function() {
    let comments = this.state.comments.map((comment, i) => {
      return <tr key={i}>
        <td onClick={ this.handleToggle.bind(this, comment) }>
          <p>{ comment.text }</p>
          { comment.isActive ? <Comment comment={comment} /> : null }
        </td>
      </tr>;
     });

    return <table>
      <tbody>{ comments }</tbody>
    </table>;
  }
});
```